# make_pipeline with StandardScalar and KerasRegressors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, pipeline

I'm trying to GridSearchCV epochs and batch_size with the following code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, shuffle=False)

X_train2 = X_train.values.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
y_train2 = np.ravel(y_train.values)

X_test2 = X_test.values.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
y_test2 = np.ravel(y_test.values)

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(500, input_shape=(1, X_train.shape[1])))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
    return model


new_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model, verbose=0)

pipe = Pipeline([('s', StandardScaler()), ('reg', new_model)])
param_gridd = {'reg__epochs': [5, 6], 'reg__batch_size': [71, 72]}
model = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=param_gridd)

# ------------------ if the following two lines are uncommented the code works -> problem with Pipeline?
# param_gridd = {'epochs':[5,6], 'batch_size': [71, 72]}
# model = GridSearchCV(estimator=new_model, param_grid=param_gridd)


fitted = model.fit(X_train2, y_train2, validation_data=(X_test2, y_test2), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

and get the following error:

```
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 722, in fit
 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1191, in _run_search
 evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 711, in evaluate_candidates
 cv.split(X, y, groups)))   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 917, in __call__
 if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
 self._dispatch(tasks)   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch
 job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/oblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in apply_async
 result = ImmediateResult(func)   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 549, in __init__
 self.results = batch()   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
 for func, args, kwargs in self.items]   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
 for func, args, kwargs in self.items]   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 528, in _fit_and_score
 estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)   
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 265, in fit
 Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)    
File "/home/geo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 202, in _fit
 step, param = pname.split('__', 1)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the naming in `param_gridd` but not really sure what is going on. Note that the code works fine when I eliminate `make_pipeline` from the code, and GridSearchCV directly on new_model.

Comment: I don't think the snippet you posted is the one causing the actual problem. Can you provide the original snippet?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your comment.  I've updated the code above, as I said previously going without Pipeline makes the code work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think that problem is with the way fit parameters for `KerasRegressor` were fed. 
`validation_data`, `shuffle` are not parameters of GridSearchCV, but the `reg`.
Try this!

```
fitted = model.fit(X_train2, y_train2,**{'reg__validation_data':(X_test2, y_test2),'reg__verbose':2, 'reg__shuffle':False} )
```

**EDIT:** 
     Based on the findings of @Vivek kumar, I have wrote a wrapper for your preprocessing.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
class custom_StandardScaler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.scaler =StandardScaler()
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X)
        return self
    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        X_new=self.scaler.transform(X)
        X_new = X_new.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))
        return X_new
```

This would help you to implement the standard scaler along with creating a new dimension. Remember we have to convert the evaluation dataset before feeding it as fit_params(), hence a seperate scaler (`offline_scaler()`) is used to transform that.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

seed = 1

boston = load_boston()
X, y = boston['data'], boston['target']

X_train, X_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(1, X_train.shape[1])))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])
    return model


new_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model, verbose=0)

param_gridd = {'reg__epochs':[2,3], 'reg__batch_size':[16,32]}
pipe = Pipeline([('s', custom_StandardScaler()),('reg', new_model)])

offline_scaler = custom_StandardScaler()
offline_scaler.fit(X_train)
X_eval2 = offline_scaler.transform(X_eval)

model = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=param_gridd,cv=3)
fitted = model.fit(X_train, y_train,**{'reg__validation_data':(X_eval2, y_eval),'reg__verbose':2, 'reg__shuffle':False} )
```

Comment: Hi AI_Learning, this doesn't work. When I print pipe.get_params().keys() it only has the following: dict_keys(['memory', 'steps', 's', 'reg', 's__copy', 's__with_mean', 's__with_std', 'reg__verbose', 'reg__build_fn']) so reg__epochs and reg__batch_size are not valid keys at all.

Comment: Hi George, You may not see these parameters listed in pipe.get_params() since these are .fit() parameters. Did you got the same error with the suggested line?

Comment: I have added an example, to show that it can work for sample dataset.

Comment: So StandardScalar cannot transform the 3D array that keras takes, yeah that makes sense. Thank for your help!

Comment: The edited solution about `custom_StandardScaler` though programmatically correct, will produce skewed results. Because validation data is scaled according to `X_train` but `GridSearchCV`  will then again divide the `X_train` and fit the custom scaler there. Which then will not be in same scale as validation data.

Comment: The assumption is that each fold, which `GridSearchCV` creates are representative of the whole X_train, hence transformation made by the `offline custom_StandardScaler`  on X_eval will not be way different from `custom_StandardScaler`  used by the `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: However X_eval is not used for early_stopping, Hence the `offline custom_StandardScaler` is just for reference to us, not going to affect the learning of the model. Once the GridSearchCV is done, we can use the pipeline itself to do the prediction on the evaluation or test data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @AI_Learning!

Answer (score 1):

As @AI_Learning said, this line should work:

```
fitted = model.fit(X_train2, y_train2, 
                   reg__validation_data=(X_test2, y_test2), 
                   reg__verbose=2, reg__shuffle=False)
```

Pipeline requires parameters to be named as `"component__parameter"`. So prepending `reg__` to the parameters work.

This however won't work because the `StandardScaler` will complain about the data dimensions. You see, when you did:

```
X_train2 = X_train.values.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
...

X_test2 = X_test.values.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
```

You made the `X_train2` and `X_test2` a 3-D data. This you have done to make it work for `LSTM` but wont work with `StandardScaler` because that requires a 2-D data of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`.

If you remove the `StandardScaler` from your pipe like this:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('reg', new_model)])
```

And try the code me and @AI_Learning suggested, it will work. This shows that its nothing to do with pipeline, but your usage of incompatible transformers together.

You can take the StandardScaler out of the pipeline and do this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, shuffle=False)

std = StandardScaler()
X_train = std.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = std.transform(X_test)

X_train2 = X_train.values.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
y_train2 = np.ravel(y_train.values)

...
...
```

Comment: So all the transformation will need to be done before i make the 3D array. This makes pipeline redundant in applications with Keras. Thanks for your answer Vivek!

Comment: @GeorgeM Well, you can have a [custom transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#custom-transformers) in between the `StandardScaler`  and KerasRegressor, which can convert the 2-d to 3-d to be passed as input to Keras as @AI_Learning suggested in his edit. But since you are passing the validation data to `KerasRegressor` which will need to use fitted `StandardScaler` out of the Pipeline, the use of pipeline is redundant and incorrect in your case.

Comment: @GeorgeM Because the validation data will need the same scaling as the X_train and X_test but if you include `StandardScaler` into the pipeline, that will again scale the data (X_train will be splitted again due to `GridSearchCV`) which will be wrong. So dont use `StandardScaler` here.

Comment: Yep, I agree with this. Thanks!